# Citing a Web Page with no author

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

For my thesis, I need to cite a lot of web-sources with no specific author. I'd like them to appear in the bibliography in the following format

```
<title> <year>, accessed <date accessed>, 
<url>
```

and as `(<title> <year>)` within the text.

(as described in this guidelines http://www.lc.unsw.edu.au/onlib/ref_elec1.html#elec3 )

Is there an easy way how to achieve this?

I was looking into `biblatex`, but it seems to be rather complicated to create a custom source type...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the biblatex manual, § 2.3.2:

> 2.3.2 Missing and Omissible Data
>
> The fields marked as ‘required’ in § 2.1.1 are not strictly
>   required in all cases. The bibliography styles which ship with
>   this package can get by with as little as a title field for most
>   entry types. A book published anonymously, a periodical without
>   an explicit editor, or a software manual without an explicit
>   author should pose no problem as far as the bibliography is
>   concerned. Citation styles, however, may have different
>   requirements. For example, an author-year citation scheme obviously requires an author/editor and a year field.
>
> You may generally use the label field to provide a substitute for
>   any missing data required for citations. How the label field is
>   employed depends on the citation style. The author-year
>   citation styles which come with this package use the label field
>   as a fallback if either the author/editor or the year is
>   missing. The numeric styles, on the other hand, do not use it at
>   all since the numeric scheme is independent of the available
>   data. The author-title styles ignore it as well, be- cause the
>   bare title is usually suƿcient to form a unique citation and a
>   title is expected to be available in any case. The label field
>   may also be used to override the non-numeric portion of the
>   automatically generated labelalpha field used by alphabetic
>   citation styles. See § 4.2.4 for details.

So, depending on the citation style you choose, you might just go with something like this:

```
@online{question64352,
  title = {Citing a Web Page with no author},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64352/citing-a-web-page-with-no-author},
  urldate = {2012-07-23}}
```